# React hooks useState initialization does not reset the state

Tags: reactjs

so I have a common component with a piece of state that should be initialized with a different value every time I visit another page. Right here I will be labeling my different pages as page A, and B.

in the component I have a initialization function to initialize the state such as below:

```
const stateInit = (inputArray) => {
  const initializedValue = {};
  // Do some condition logic to store initial value into the const variable

  // log to see the changes
  console.log("initializedValue: ", initializedValue);

  return initializedValue
}
```

in my functional component, I have declare the state as follow:

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState<Object>(stateInit(props.inputArray));

// log to see the changes
console.log("myState: ", myState);
```

The `inputArray` will be different depending on which page of A, B I'm at.

This issue only occurs when I go between pages A <-> B

The expected behavior is when I switch between the two pages, the first console log will be the new value related to the page Im in, and the second console log has the state initialized with the new value related to the page.

The actual behavior is when I switch between the two pages, the first console log will be the new value related to the page Im in, but the second console log has the state with the previous initialized value.

I couldn't seem to figure out why the state is not initialized correctly. Does anyone have any clue about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the same instance of the functional component is used by both pages, then `myState` is initialized only once for all the pages and then the value is carried on between them. What might be misleading is that `stateInit` will be called every time there's a rerender but its value will be discarded apart from the time when the component is first instantiated. You might want to use [lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state):

```
useState<Object>(() => stateInit(props.inputArray))
```

to figure out when the component is actually created (`stateInit` will be called only then).

Comment: This actually made sense, by checking the state called as you suggested I do see that the `stateInit` is only called once. I am now added a `useEffect` to make sure that it updates every time the page changes depending on the param of the URL, and it is working correctly. Other than this I can't think of any other way to fix this issue, do you have any better practice advice on this?

Comment: Oh actually, I thought I had it working, but it seems like it didn't work, it is still having the same behavior

Comment: Its hard to suggest a good solution without looking at the bigger sample of your code. A straightforward approach would be to force component recreation by, for example, adding `inputArray` as `key` prop to the component if `inputArray` is only different at page change.

Comment: I see, makes sense, it's hard to show a bigger sample since it is part of an entire website. I will go ahead and try to use the key prop approach and see where I get from there. Thanks a lot for the point out tho! That helped me to address the issue

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your full code? this may be hapening because `props.inputArray` is getting undefined when changing from A->B, but i can't confirm without the rest of the code.

Best of Luck

Comment: I consoled logged out to check with the `inputArray` too and there is value for it. Thanks for the suggestion. I think in my case it is the reason @marzelin mentioned above that caused this to happen